# Hard freezes when RAM is exceeding

Tags: ram, swap

I have 8GB RAM, when memory is exceeded (chrome + vbox + something else):

1. hard mouse freezes
2. permanently lit SSD led
3. in 90% of cases I can't login in tty, system without any response, necessary to reset only
4. in 10% I login in tty and kill chrome or vbox and system is back to life

I run `free -m` every 2 seconds, and specifically fill all RAM, when free swap begins to decrease - it happens. The same thing happens with disabled swap, when free memory is decreasing to zero.

Other devices with Ubuntu 14.04, and 12.04 have same problem.

How I can solve this?

```
Linux E5550 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: when memory is involved: start by checking if the modules are perfect.  But ... a "hard" freeze to me means a keyboard lock and requiring a reboot ;-)  If the system sort of still works (but slow) you can also start "top" on a tty and check what is hogging the system (I would asssume either chrome or vbox and not both(?))

Comment: How much main memory (RAM+swap) does your system have in total (see `/proc/meminfo`)? Is the swap space on a reasonably fast storage medium? What are the values of other relevant virtual memory management parameters like `vm.swappiness`?

Comment: good idea would probably be to increase swappines and amount of swap

Comment: @Rinzwind, yes. I can't login in tty even

Comment: @DavidFoerster, 
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 6000
vm.swappiness = 15
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 50
vm.laptop_mode=0
vm.dirty_ratio=10
vm.dirty_background_ratio=10
vm.drop_caches=3


$ free -m<br/>
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached<br/>
Mem:          7879       7523        355        711        252       2141<br/>
-/+ buffers/cache:       5129       2749<br/>
Swap:         8083        411       7672<br/>

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: How big is the Virtual Machine .On my 6GB RAM PC with no swap I can run 2GB VirtualBox and Unity3D and blender .RAM usage is about 5GB.It never froze up because of RAM.

Comment: I have exactly this same problem. In my case usually when multiple applications are open and I start to build C++ code in Qt Creator something bad happens. Effectively it feels like a fork bomb.

Comment: Shouldn't the program requesting the ram amount that exceeds the limits crash, instead of the whole system freezing?